# Bind BYTEA to PGSQL PDO Prepared Statement in PHP5

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I cannot seem to find a way to bind a bytea to a prepared statement using PHP5's PDO and PostgreSQL. Heres how i imagine this working...

```
$this->stmtPDO = $this->hPDO->prepare (
    'INSERT INTO board.feedback ("created", "title", "payloaddata")
     VALUES (NOW(), :title, :payload) RETURNING psk;', 
    array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR, PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL)
);
$this->stmtPDO->bindParam(":payload", $payload);
$this->stmtPDO->bindParam(":title", $title);
$this->stmtPDO->execute();
```

Has anyone found an easy solution for this?

Comment: Have you tried to set the type of the parameter to `PDO::PARAM_LOB` e.g. `$this->stmtPDO->bindParam(":payload", $payload, PDO::PARAM_LOB);`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to set the type of the parameter to `PDO::PARAM_LOB`?
E.g.

```
$this->stmtPDO->bindParam(":payload", $payload, PDO::PARAM_LOB);?
```