# Storing images in bytea fields in a PostgreSQL database

Tags: php, postgresql, heroku, bytea

I stored an image in a PostgreSQL database with column type bytea using PHP. The problem is every time I try to load the image in a browser it does not appear. The Firefox developer console says the image is either truncated or corrupt.

The PHP code:

```
//code for inserting into the database
if(array_key_exists('submit_pic', $_POST)){
$user=$_SESSION['name'];
if(isset($_FILES['thumbnail'])&&$_FILES['thumbnail']['size']>0){
$fi =  $_FILES['thumbnail']['tmp_name'];
$p=fopen($fi,'r');
$data=fread($p,filesize($fi));
$data=addslashes($data);
$dat= pg_escape_bytea($data); 
$q="update userinfo set image='{$dat}' where email='$user'";
$e=pg_query($q)or die(pg_last_error());

// code for retreving from database
require_once('conn.php');
session_start();
$user=$_SESSION['name'];
pg_query('SET bytea_output = "escape";');
$lquery ="select image from userinfo where email='$user'";
$lq = pg_query($lquery)or die(pg_last_error());
$lqq=pg_fetch_row($lq,'image');
header("conent-type:image");
echo pg_unescape_bytea($lqq[0]);
```

and i need to store the uploaded image in a database- i am actually using heroku thanks

Comment: Why do you *need* to store images in database? It's inefficient in every way imaginable.

Comment: @user80168 There are at least some ways where it is far from inefficient. It can be much quicker to fetch small images like thumbnails in a single request. It can be a lot more efficient than playing awful games with file renaming, two-phase commit and `fsync()` if you require proper ACID semantics and data consistency for your images. It's easier to back up at small scales (but much harder at large scales). Like anything else it's a trade-off where sometimes it can be great, other times it can be awful, mostly it's just ok.

Comment: Sometimes efficiency is not he most important aspect.  All projects I have worked have had some form of compromise.  As a professional, I try to identify the most import aspects and address them first.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### TL;DR:

Delete `addslashes($data)`. It's redundant here.

### Double-escaping .. twice

```
$data=fread($p,filesize($fi));
$data=addslashes($data);
$dat= pg_escape_bytea($data);
```

You read the data in, escape it as if it were a string literal, then convert it to bytea octal or hex escapes. It could never work that way around even if `pg_escape_bytea` was sane, which it isn't.

PHP's `pg_escape_bytea` appears to *double-escape* the output so it can be inserted into a string literal. This is incredibly ugly, but there doesn't appear to be an alternative that doesn't do this double-escaping, so you can't seem to use parameterised statements for bytea in PHP. You should still do so for everything else.

In this case, simply removing the `addslashes` line for the data read in from the file is sufficient.

Test case showing that `pg_escape_bytea` double-escapes (and always uses the old, inefficient octal escapes, too):

```
<?php
# oh-the-horror.php
print pg_escape_bytea("Blah binary\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04 blah");
?>
```

Run:

```
php oh-the-horror.php
```

Result:

```
Blah binary\\000\\001\\002\\003\\004 blah
```

See the doubled backslashes? That's because it's assuming you're going to interpolate it into SQL as a string, which is extremely memory inefficient, ugly, and a very bad habit. You don't seem to get any alternative, though.

Among other things this means that:

```
pg_unescape_bytea(pg_escape_bytea("\x01\x02\x03"));
```

... produces the *wrong result*, since `pg_unescape_bytea` is not actually the reverse of `pg_escape_bytea`. It also makes it impossible to feed the output of `pg_escape_bytea` into `pg_query_params` as a parameter, you have to interpolate it in.

### Decoding

If you're using a modern PostgreSQL, it probably sets `bytea_output` to `hex` by default. That means that if I write my data to a `bytea` field then fetch it back, it'll look something like this:

```
craig=> CREATE TABLE byteademo(x bytea);
CREATE TABLE
craig=> INSERT INTO byteademo(x) VALUES ('Blah binary\\000\\001\\002\\003\\004 blah');
INSERT 0 1
craig=> SELECT * FROM byteademo ;
                                     x                                      
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 \x426c61682062696e6172795c3030305c3030315c3030325c3030335c30303420626c6168
(1 row)
```

"Um, what", you might say? It's fine, it's just PostgreSQL's slightly more compact hex representation of `bytea`. `pg_unescape_bytea` will handle it fine and produce the same raw bytes as output ... if you have a modern PHP and `libpq`.  On older versions you'll get garbage and will need to set `bytea_output` to `escape` for `pg_unescape_bytea` to handle it.

### What you should do instead

Use PDO.

It has sane(ish) support for `bytea`.

```
$sth = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO mytable(somecol, byteacol) VALUES (:somecol, :byteacol)');
$sth->bindParam(':somecol', 'bork bork bork');
$sth->bindParam(':byteacol', $thebytes, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$sth->execute();
```

See:

- [PHP: Large Objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php), which has an example of exactly what you want;
- [PDOStatement::bindParam](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)
- [how to store serialized object with namespace in database using pdo php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20959085/398670)
- [Bind BYTEA to PGSQL PDO Prepared Statement in PHP5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5313066/398670)

You may also want to look in to PostgreSQL's lob (large object) support, which provides a streaming, seekable interface that's still fully transactional.

### *Now, on to my soap box*

If PHP had a real distinction between "byte string" and "text string" types, you wouldn't even need `pg_escape_bytea` as the database driver could do it for you. None of this ugliness would be required. Unfortunately, there are no separate string and bytes types in PHP.

Please, use PDO with parameterised statements as much as possible.

Where you can't, at least use `pg_query_params` and parameterised statements. PHP's `addslashes` is not an alternative, it's inefficient, ugly, and doesn't understand database specific escaping rules. You still have to manually escape `bytea` if you're not using PDO for icky historical reasons, but everything else should go through parameterised statements.

For guidance on `pg_query_params`:

- [Bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/), PHP section.
- [The PHP manual on `pg_query_params`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php)

Answer (score 3):

It is better to use postgres *large objects* if you really have to store images in your database. In the **userinfo** table instead of the **image** itself store just a link to it as **loid** (large object id).

Insert an image into the database:

```
    pg_query("begin");  // pg_lo functions need to be run in a transaction
    $loid = pg_lo_import('full_path_and_file_name');
    pg_query("update userinfo set loid=$loid where email='$user'");
    pg_query("commit");
```

Retrieve an image from the database:

```
    $rs = pg_query("select loid from userinfo where email='$user'");
    $loid = pg_fetch_row($rs, 0)[0];
    pg_query("begin");
    $blob = pg_lo_open($loid, "r");
    header("Content-type: image");
    pg_lo_read_all($blob);
    pg_lo_close($blob);
    pg_query("commit");
```

The **loid** field is of type oid (of course you can name it as you want).

Consider using the `lo` type [from the `lo` extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/lo.html) instead of using the `oid` type. Using `lo` gives you automatic "orphan removal", where deleting a row from a table will automatically remove the associated large object, so it's good for cases where a table row "owns" a large object.

Storing links to images is especially convenient in case you use one image more than one time. However, you should pay attention to delete unused images from your database (PHP function pg_lo_unlink()).

[Large objects in postgres documentation.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/largeobjects.html)

[PHP manual: pg_lo_import.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-lo-import.php)

Comment: thanks guys it is working like a charm now sorry i couldnt vote up any answers they i need 15 reputation-just joined stackoverflow yesterday- after i removed the addslashes function it the pictures began to load @craig ringer you sure are a pro!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Large objects are a bit more of a pain to manage, though; at minimum you'll want to use the `lo` extension so you get automatic deletion of orphaned objects. Personally I'd prefer `bytea` for things like thumbnails; it'll be stored out-of-line in a TOAST table so it won't impact the performance of queries that don't ask for it, but it's convenient and quick to access when required.

Comment: I have been using large objects for years. Avoiding orphans seemed to me so obvoius I did not even mention of it. I have edited the answer for a future reader. Thanks for your note.

Answer (score 0):

I found a strange way of getting this to work too without using PDO.

Use a text field in postgresql instead of bytea. 
On insert, prep your data like this:

`$imgdta = pg_escape_string(bin2hex($filedata));`

Then when you want to display the file after your query, use:

`echo pack("H*", $img["filedata"]);`

I'm not going to pretend I get why, but this worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

As the source of your data is a file in the file system so it seems to me efficient to find an inspiration [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1742/how-to-insert-file-data-into-a-postgresql-bytea-column):

In your db create an auxiliary function, run as superuser:

```
create or replace function bytea_import(p_path text, p_result out bytea) 
                   language plpgsql as $$
declare
  l_oid oid;
begin
  select lo_import(p_path) into l_oid;
  select lo_get(l_oid) INTO p_result;
  perform lo_unlink(l_oid);
end;$$
security definer;
```

In your php execute a query like:

```
#make sure that postgres will have access to the file
chmod($_FILES['thumbnail']['tmp_name'], 0644);
pg_query("update userinfo set image=(select bytea_import('".$_FILES['thumbnail']['tmp_name']."')) where email='$user'");
```