# how to store serialized object with namespace in database using pdo php

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

When i try to store serialized object with namespace i cant do that beacuse i got error unterminated quoted string at or near "'O:22:"protect\classes\Router". Code:

```
$router = new protect\classes\Router();
$tmp = serialize($router);

$dsn = 'pgsql:dbname=system;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'postgres';
$password = 'mypassword';
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, $options);
$pdo->exec('SET search_path = temporary');
$pdo->query("SELECT replace_value('protect\classes\Router','$tmp','serialized_classes')");  // this is my function it`s work fine
```

If i use php function addslashes before query executed for exampe

```
  $tmp = addslashes(serialize($router));
```

the query is successful executed. Unfortunately serialized object with additional slashes is disorder.

I will grateful for help with this topic.

Comment: You didn't *properly* escape your data.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to post the source code of your `replace_value` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things wrong here, but the biggest is that you aren't using query parameters.

*Don't* use `addslashes`. If you find yourself using that, you should think "oops, I need to go fix the query so I use parameters instead".

In this case, you should be writing something like:

```
$sth = $pdo->prepare('SELECT replace_value(?, ?, ?)');
$sth->execute(array('protect\classes\Router', $tmp, 'serialized_classes'));
```

You haven't mentioned what the data type of the argument you pass the serialized data to is. The above will only work if it is `text` or `varchar` or similar.

If it's `bytea` like it should be for serialized object data, you must tell PHP that the parameter is a binary field:

```
$sth = $pdo->prepare('SELECT replace_value(:router, :serialbytes, :mode)');
$sth->bindParam(':router', 'protect\classes\Router');
$sth->bindParam(':mode', 'serialized_classes');
$sth->bindParam(':serialbytes', $tmp, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$sth->execute();
```

Note the use of `PDO::PARAM_LOB` to tlel PDO that `$tmp` contains binary data to be passed to PostgreSQL as `bytea`.

(It's fine to put constants like `'protect\classes\Router'` directly into your queries, btw, so long as you split them out into params if they ever become variables. I mostly separated them because I find it more readable in a query like this.)

Comment: first thing when i use code with bindParam i got error: The arguments passed to bindParam have to be reference, so i put instead string a varaible. I got effect but i got next error. My serialized object is not right with UTF-8 encoding. my serialbytes columns is type text. So i change to bytea now working fine, but in row i have just something like "<binary data>". I`m not sure if i get this (<binary data>) from database i can use my serialized object? So i try too use you first example with preapare and execute(array(...)) all working fine but my serialized object in db i cut at half.

Comment: @ZiupeX It's probably cut in half because it contains nulls (zero bytes, `'\0'`. If so, you *cannot* store it in a `text` column, you *must* use `bytea`. As for how to read `bytea` from the DB - you `SELECT` it like any other column. If you are having problems with that, *post a new question* tagged `php postgresql` with appropriate details, including storage and retrieval code, SQL, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing same problem - and found out here that this is the zer-byte problems.
After some development I created an adapter for Zend Serializer (ZF2) that overloads serialize/unserialize methods in a way that it will be possible to store these serialized values in PostgreSQL.

The code you can find below - hopefully it will somehow useful :)

```
use Zend\Serializer\Adapter\PhpSerialize;

/**
 *
 * Class overloads serialization methods so serialized objects will be PostgreSQL safe
 * For further information on safe/unsafe objects:
 * http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php#96504
 *
 */
class PostgresSerialize extends PhpSerialize {

    const DEFAULT_SAFE_NULLBYTE_REPLACEMENT = "~~NULL_BYTE~~";

    protected static $serializedFalse = null;

    public function serialize($value) {
        $serializedString = parent::serialize($value);
        if (strpos($this->options['safe_nullbyte_replacement'], $serializedString))
            throw new \RuntimeException('Cannot perform safe nullbyte replace operation since safe_nullbyte_replacement="' .  $this->options['safe_nullbyte_replacement'] . '"value already exists in the serialized string', \Zend\Log\Logger::ERR);
        if ($this->options['safe_nullbyte_replacement'] == null)
            $this->options['safe_nullbyte_replacement'] = self::DEFAULT_SAFE_NULLBYTE_REPLACEMENT;
        return str_replace("\0", $this->options['safe_nullbyte_replacement'], $serializedString);
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized) {
        if ($this->options['safe_nullbyte_replacement'] == null)
            $this->options['safe_nullbyte_replacement'] = self::DEFAULT_SAFE_NULLBYTE_REPLACEMENT;
        $serializedString = str_replace($this->options['safe_nullbyte_replacement'], "\0", $serialized);
        return parent::unserialize($serializedString);
    }

}
```