# How to store and retrieve PHP serialize() in PostgreSQL?

Tags: php, postgresql, encoding, character-encoding

I just converted to PostgreSQL from MySQL. In PostgreSQL my field (`jobInfo`) is a blob in (`bytea`) format.

```
SELECT folderName, jobInfo
FROM jobs
```

In mySQL, that field came in as a string that could be unserialized. However, when I read the data in from postgres, it comes in looking like this:

> \x613a31353a7b733a31373a2266696c65466f726d617456657273696f6e223b733a333a22342e30223b733a373a226a6f62
>   [.....]

Is there a way, in PHP or postgres, to decode that back to the serialized string of text characters?

**UPDATE**
Per request, here is the code used to initially create the mySQL Blob field:

```
$theJobInfo = serialize($theJobInfo);
```

And SQL query:

```
UPDATE `jobs` SET `jobInfo` = theJobInfo
WHERE `folderName` = 'myFolderName'
```

Comment: If that bytea field represents a PHP Object, how do you know it will make sense as a string of characters?

Comment: Show the code you use to set the field in mysql/php originally.

Comment: Because it's serialized. I have saved and retrieved this data thousands of times from mySQL, so for that reason I do believe it makes sense as a string of characters. I have updated the original post with the PHP/SQL code per your request.

Comment: Paste the schema for jobs... `\d jobs` in psql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code retrieved the serialized string from the contents of the postgres ByteA field:

`$serializedString = pg_unescape_bytea($contentsOfPostGresByteAField);`

Thanks to [Sergey Pashkov](http://valentina-db.com/en/discussion-forums/2727-moving-from-mysql-postgres-best-way-to-store-php-objects-in-mysql,-retrieve-in-postgres#reply-2741) for the tip!

Comment: Is this a custom module?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily convert to and from `bytea` and `text`, like this

```
SELECT convert_from('foo'::bytea, 'UTF8');
```

However, I don't think that's relevant.

You're using the [`serailize()` function of php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)

> Note that this is a binary string which may include null bytes, and needs to be stored and handled as such. For example, `serialize()` output should generally be stored in a `BLOB` field in a database, rather than a `CHAR` or `TEXT` field.

That function returns binary data. And likewise, `unserialize()` *expects* binary data. If you don't want to use binary data in the php, you can make `jobs.jobinfo` a `jsonb` type and send the result of `json_encode()` to it, and then `json_decode()` from it..

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: I *do* want to use binary data. That's why I'm saving it to a Blob field in mySQL.

Comment: The question is, once I get it into a postgres ByteA field, how do I retrieve it as a serialized string that I can then unserialize?

Comment: You don't retrieve it as as a text string. You retrieve it as a "binary string", or "scalar" if php wasn't dumb af. Then you feed the scalar (with its binary contents) to `unserialize()`.

Comment: json has difficulty with PHP objects. It's possible to json encode PHP objects via JsonSerializable, but decoding them back to the original objects (not stdClass objects) is slow. That's why I'm seeking to find out if it's possible to use the serialized PHP objects.

Comment: Our comments crossed.

Comment: Okay, very good. What is the correct way to retrieve it from ByteA as a binary string or scalar? Is it `SELECT convert_from('foo'::bytea, 'UTF8');` as you posted a few comments ago?

Comment: No, just `var row = SELECT jobInfo FROM jobs`. And, then just `unserialize(row[jobInfo])` or whatever.

Comment: As I noted in the original post, the contents of the ByteA field are not in string format. They are `"\x613a31353a7b733a31373a2266696c65466f726d617456657273696f6e223b733a333a22342e30223b733a373a226a6f624e616d65223b733a34313a224e4743462d4356412d50726f6d6f5669642d"`[.....];  Running unserialize on this returns false or 0. This question is the basis of my original post.

Comment: I have no idea what's going on. All I know is you wanting to turn binary data that unserialize expects into a string of text (which is impossible) is not going to solve the problem. Perhaps you need to paste the schema, or provide a test case to produce the issue.

Comment: In mySQL that binary blob data comes back to PHP as a text string, including null characters where necessary for PHP objects, that can be unserialized. So, it is very doable. Not impossible at all. :)

Comment: It **has** to be bytea. That's the end of the story. Learn to use it. Don't know how to help you with what's given. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20961819/124486

Comment: Solved it yesterday. Will post solution here as soon as work permits.