# Storing Zip file in Postgres

Tags: php, mysql, sql, postgresql, encoding

I've been storing the contents of zip files in a LONGBLOB in a MySQL database, but I'm moving to Postgres.  From what I've read, the equivalent to LONGBLOB in Postgres is bytea.  Unfortunately, I can't get the zip contents to write to the database.  First, I got this error:

```
Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8"
 0x5c
```

Then I created a new database with SQL_ASCII encoding (the previous had UTF8), and got this error:

```
PHP Warning:  pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "v╘▓ú5"
LINE 2: ...√╢V[úB√▬┌»å⌐²└ù╙±b±≡ß▼┐π}°ï»┌G╜₧╧εo»~°0o╞W/_╝ƒL¢\'v╘▓ú5;Ω░#╩...
```

Is there any way to create a database/table/column in Postgres without encoding?  If not, how should I store this information?  I tried using pg_escape_bytea but that produces errors when I try to unzip the contents.  Not sure that this really matters, but here's the PHP I'm using to write to the database:

```
$content = file_get_contents($zipLocation);
$content = addslashes($content);

$sql="INSERT INTO ZIP_TBL ( BUILD, CONTENT)
    VALUES ('$build', '$content')";

if (!pg_query($con,$sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . pg_last_error($con));
}
```

Comment: Can't you use a bound parameter and let the PostgreSQL driver deal with properly encoding the binary data?

Comment: Never, ever, ever use `addslashes`. If you're using it, that's a giant flashing warning saying "probable security bug here". In this case you should *clearly* be using a parameterzed query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the `bytea` input formats is hexadecimal. So use `bin2hex`

```
$content = file_get_contents($zipLocation);
$content = '\\x' . bin2hex($content);

$sql="
    insert into zip_tbl ( build, content)
    values ('$build', E'$content')
";
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-binary.html#AEN5318

http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php

BTW, if you are not aware, you are susceptible to SQL injection.

Comment: This worked for me, I just had to use `$content = substr($content, 2);` and `$content = hex2bin($content);` when reading it from the database

Answer (score 2):

Now is a good opportunity to switch to PDO, which does this sort of thing cleanly and sanely.

[Here's an earlier answer I wrote on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17121791/398670), which discusses the numerous ways in which the old-style PostgreSQL driver is truly awful for binary data.

The short version is that your code should be more like:

```
$sth = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO mytable(somecol, byteacol) VALUES (:somecol, :byteacol)');
$sth->bindParam(':somecol', 'bork bork bork');
$sth->bindParam(':byteacol', $thebytes, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$sth->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Definitely helpful, although I ended up using Clodoaldo's method.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use base64encode() function:

```
$content = file_get_contents($zipLocation);
$content = base64encode($content);

$sql="INSERT INTO ZIP_TBL ( BUILD, CONTENT)
    VALUES ('$build', '$content')";

if (!pg_query($con,$sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . pg_last_error($con));
}
```

And when you will need this data back, use base64decode() function. Also, type of your column needs to be text to store this data.

> > string base64_encode ( string $data )
> >
> > string base64_decode ( string $data [, bool $strict = false ] )

http://php.net//manual/en/function.base64-decode.php

http://php.net//manual/en/function.base64-encode.php

Comment: Using this method I don't see any errors writing to the database, but when I try to read from the database the zip file is still corrupted ( I didn't forget to use base64_decode). I could post the php code I'm using to read from the database if that would help.

Comment: i wrote simple script to test it at my local machine and it's all right.

Paste your code, will check it

Comment: You might need to change database collation