# Converting a zip file to bytea to store in postgres - python

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, bytea

I would like to store zip files in a postgres database using python.

It seems like this should be easy, but I can't work it out.

This is what I've tried - my issue is how to convert the zipfile to a `bytea` object.

```py
from zipfile import ZipFile
from io import BytesIO, StringIO


filename = "test.zip"
with ZipFile(filename, 'w') as zip_archive:
    binary_stream = BytesIO(zip_archive)

def store_blob(filename, blob):
    with db.engine.connect() as connection:
        res = connection.execute('''INSERT INTO test (filename, model_file) VALUES (%s,                     %s)''', (filename, blob ))


store_blob(filename, binary_stream)
```

Comment: Why are you opening the file for write?

Comment: attempting to convert to bytea - is there a way of doing that without opening it?

Comment: Does the file, `test.zip` already exist?

Comment: yes, I just need to get it from the disk to a database

Comment: What is the actual error that you are observing? If you add an error message or stacktrace, there are more chances to correctly diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file already exists, then your code should look like this:

```
def store_blob(filename, blob):
    with db.engine.connect() as connection:
        res = connection.execute(
             '''INSERT INTO test (filename, model_file) VALUES (%s,%s)''', 
             (filename, blob ))

filename = "test.zip"
with open(filename, 'rb') as zip_archive:
    store_blob(filename, zip_archive.read())
```

Your code does not need to know about the format of the file.  All you want to do is to open it for `read` with the `binary` flag to prevent decoding, and pass its `read()` (which produces a `b''`) as a parameter to the `execute()`

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's an accepted answer here already [Storing Zip file in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126891/storing-zip-file-in-postgres)

You can use the `bin2hex()` function as demonstrated in the above answer.

Info on postgres bytea datatypes: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-binary.html#AEN5318

Comment: OP asked specifically about python implementation, not php.