# am i misunderstanding this~ Why is COPY changing the output? (PGPLSQL)

Tags: database, postgresql, file-transfer

I'm very close to solving a big problem that i'm having at the moment and this is the last bit. I just don't know why the output is different to what's in the database when i need it EXACTLY the same.

Reading the data before entering the database:

```
[NULL][NULL][NULL][SO][etc.......]
```

Reading the data from `COPY` to text file:

```
\\000\\000\\000\\016[etc...} (it matches, basically)
```

Reading the data after `COPY` using binary format

```
PGCOPY
ÿ
[NULL][NULL][NULL][EOT][etc.......] (first line changes a fair bit)
(rest of the data stays exactly the same.)
˜ÿÿ
```

The postgresql query being run for test's sake:

```
COPY (SELECT byteacolumn FROM tablename WHERE id = 1) TO 'C:\path\file' (format:Binary);
```

So using the binary format gives me almost what i need but not quite. I could botch to ignore the added lines, but i wouldn't know what the first line of data should be.

**TL;DR:** `COPY` is adding lines and changing the first row of my data. How do i make it stop? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binary `COPY` format is really only designed to be consumed by a `COPY FROM` command, so it contains a lot of metadata to allow Postgres to interpret it.

After the first two lines, the next 9 bytes are also part of the header. The next 2 bytes give the number of fields in the following record, and the next 4 bytes give the number of bytes in the following field. Only then does the actual data begin.

The full details of the format can be found in the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-copy.html#AEN72069), but be aware that they could change in a future release.

(However, assuming this is the same problem you were asking about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31081736/transfering-raw-data-to-and-from-postgresql-database), I think this is the wrong way to go about it. You were on the right track with `lo_import`/`lo_export`.)